# How does instancing work for a device with subclassed execution environment?

Tags: uml, deployment-diagram

I have a device with an execution environment as such:

[image: Base device with base environment]

The idea is to describe general properties for any deployment, and then instance it with specific subclasses. But I'm confused how instancing works in this case. Could be tooling limitations throwing me off track. Tools set aside, from a pure UML perspective, how would I describe a device instance with an environment execution child element being an instance of a specific subclass, in a way that does not imply there is *both* a generalized and subclassed variant of the execution environment?

This is what I come up with in my tool (EA):

[image: Instances of device and environment]

But my strict interpretation of above is instance ":Base Computer" having one instance each of Base Environment and Sub1.

Comment: Why would you expect `Base` and `Sub`? The latter is just a generalization of `Base Environment`.